# Assign Previous Value to row in R Conditional on Data Type

Tags: r

I am trying to Tidy a data frame in R. My raw data file includes 2 types of tables in a massive data frame, and they are labeled by a Record Indicator (RI) value = 100 or 200.

- RI == 100 correspond to important details like unit of measure (UOM) and ID references for the following sequential data (RI==200).  The columns are RI, ID, and UOM.
- RI == 200 corresponds to the data I need in the data frame. The columns are RI, Measure1, Measure2, Measure3, and Time. Note these are not always the same length as I may have more history for certain IDs.

An example of my df looks like:

```
RI Measure1 Measure2 Measure3 Time
100 Scott cm N/A N/A
200 1.6 0.2 1.5 0
200 1.3 0.5 0.6 1
200 8.1 7.5 0.8 2
100 James inches N/A N/A
200 0.1 0.1 0.5 0
200 0.1 0.1 0.3 1
200 0.5 0.5 0.6 2
200 0.1 0.5 0.1 3
```

I added 2 columns with initial values in my expanded data frame:

- df$ID <- df$Measure1
- df$UOM <-df$Measure2

I need to replace the values for all RI=200 to be equal to the previous value to pull down the ID and UOM for each row.

Finally, I can trim my data to df[df$RI==200,]

How do I for a given row (conditional on it being RI==200), replace the value for df$ID and df$UOM with the previous value?

This is what I tried to no avail:

```
apply(df[df$RI==200,],1,function(x) {df$ID <-df$ID[-1]})
```

Comment: I did not understand what you need but seems like looking at `lead` and `lag` from `dplyr` package will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have tried.

```
df=read.table(text="
RI Measure1 Measure2 Measure3 Time
100 Scott cm N/A N/A
200 1.6 0.2 1.5 0
200 1.3 0.5 0.6 1
200 8.1 7.5 0.8 2
100 James inches N/A N/A
200 0.1 0.1 0.5 0
200 0.1 0.1 0.3 1
200 0.5 0.5 0.6 2
200 0.1 0.5 0.1 3", header=T)

f=df$RI
counter=0
for(i in 1:length(f)){
    if(f[i]==100) counter=counter+1
    f[i]=counter
}

df$f=f

df100=df[df$RI==100,c("Measure1","Measure2","f")]
colnames(df100)=c("ID","UOM","f")
df200=df[df$RI==200,]
dplyr::left_join(df200,df100, by="f")
```

Which prints

```
   RI Measure1 Measure2 Measure3 Time f    ID    UOM
1 200      1.6      0.2      1.5    0 1 Scott     cm
2 200      1.3      0.5      0.6    1 1 Scott     cm
3 200      8.1      7.5      0.8    2 1 Scott     cm
4 200      0.1      0.1      0.5    0 2 James inches
5 200      0.1      0.1      0.3    1 2 James inches
6 200      0.5      0.5      0.6    2 2 James inches
7 200      0.1      0.5      0.1    3 2 James inches
```

Comment: You are a superstar!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem so that other people won't waste their time.